# Why is my iPhone 5S overheating so much?

Tags: battery, iphone, restart, warranty

Activities such as:

1. Phone Calls that last around 10 minutes
2. 3G Browsing for 5 - 7 minutes
3. Watching videos for 5 minutes
4. Using apps such as facebook / instagram etc for 5 - 7 minutes,
   lead to my iPhone 5S severely overheating.

It heats so much at times that it can't be held any more and you have to set it down for it to cool down.

At times, it randomly restarts when plugged in. When it starts to heat the battery drops sharply and sometimes the phone simply dies

I'm fairly certain that the hardware in my phone is being affected with this overheating

My first year phone warranty ends in 10 days and I'm contemplating whether I should give it to Apple India Service and if they will replace my phone.

Any Solutions? Suggestions? Experiences with Indian Apple Service Centres?

Comment: If you've only 10 days left to think about it - take it & see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are several other answers, I'll contribute my own [$0.02](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents) for future readers as well.

The device is overheating due to processes consuming the device's physical memory and is causing it to overheat. Activities like calling and data usage often requires a lot of battery power, which then leads to the device over-heating.

Some temporary solutions would be to:

- If you are standing in the sun, remove the device from the heat.
- Closing background applications when not using them to avoid battery consumption.

  - This also includes disabling WiFi and/or service when not in use.
  - Games are very bad at power consumption, "Clash of Clans"  being a major example using up to `10.3mAh/min` sometimes even when not in use.
  - Avoid the use of 3rd party cables (as mentioned by another user who answered).
- Put your phone into sleep mode every once in a while the system can cool down and regain some of the used RAM.
- Delete some apps, the less apps using your battery and memory the better.

---

As for long term solution, **get the new phone**. Even though the device heating to rather hot temperatures can be normal, after a short period of data usage it shouldn't. Often times it is some faulty hardware that is causing the problems.

If you aren't in the situation to get a new phone, then a factory reset is the way to go. This will delete any apps or cached data that would be causing the battery over-consumption and would restore the device to its intended factory abilities.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me but different iPhone model. I got hints from here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4338574?start=0

Starting from fresh (factory reset) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mine did the same thing. I wiped and restored it to a backup several times with no improvement. The Genius at The Apple Store couldn't figure out what was wrong and eventually replaced it. The new one does the same thing, but not with as much frequency and it doesn't randomly restart itself with the apple screen as the old one did.

My original 5s always ran hot, but the problems became magnified tenfold with the introduction of iOS 8.

I think swapping it out for a replacement is a good idea, though you may still experience similar problems at least it'll be a fresh battery that's getting pounded rather than a year old battery that is already deprecated from use.

Given that Apple no longer bothers applying any quality control to their software, it would seem they've decided it's more cost effective for them to repeatedly replace hardware that fails as a result of their unfixed software bugs than pay engineers to eliminate those bugs before releasing said software. And they're right! Most (American) people will just suffer with a glitchy, unusable piece of garbage rather than go to the trouble -- and it frequently and intentionally is a lot of trouble -- of demanding a company honor their own warranty.

Answer (score 0):

don't use a third party cable or plug when charging your iPhone, they can damage your iPhone, causing them to overheat.